# PHP SoapClient not working - no error

Tags: php, soap-client, bronto

I have some code that connects to a newsletter service via SOAP. It works with no problem on our dev server, but on our live server it doesn't work at all. It's not returning any errors; just a blank white page. I've put some error_logs into the code and found exactly where it stops working - on the line creating the new SoapClient. Is there some kind of server config that needs to be set? Our code is identical between dev and prod, so the only thing I can figure is a server issue. (Note that the first chunk of code below was provided by the newsletter service, not written by me.)

```
# bronto API session/connection setup
ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", "0");
date_default_timezone_set('America/Chicago');

$wsdl = "https://api.bronto.com/v4?wsdl";
$url = "https://api.bronto.com/v4";

/*error log statements up to this point return what is expected; 
  an error log after the following line (starting with $client = new SoapClient) 
  does not get triggered at all. */

$client = new SoapClient($wsdl, array('trace' => 1, 'encoding' => 'UTF-8')); 
$client->__setLocation($url);

$token = "XXX";
$sessionId = $client->login(array("apiToken" => $token))->return;
$client->__setSoapHeaders(array(new SoapHeader("http://api.bronto.com/v4",
        'sessionHeader',
         array('sessionId' => $sessionId))));
```

I've also tried something like this to explicitly see any errors, but no luck - still nothing in the error log.

```
try {  
  $client = @new SoapClient($wsdl, array('trace' => 1, 'encoding' => 'UTF-8')); 
} 
  catch (SoapFault $E) {  
    error_log($E->faultstring) ;
}  
error_log("ok");
```

Comment: I would check the installed PHP packages on the dev server and compare to the Prod server. http://fr2.php.net/manual/en/soap.setup.php

Comment: Turn on error_reporting. A "white screen" usually means PHP puked and has been set to hide all errors, so you get nothing. Also, if PHP has been configured to do so, check the server (and/or php's) error logs to see if there's anything in there. It may not be spitting out error messages in the browser, but they could be getting logged somewhere.

Comment: @Phil, thanks. I was just doing that, and surprise! Our live (hosted) server doesn't have SOAP installed at all! If you want to move that comment into an answer I'll accept it so you get credit.

Comment: @Marc, we do have error_reporting on, and as I said, error_log was showing nothing on the line that was blowing up.

Comment: odd - i had a similar problem but when I did the try/catch block it bombed out the errors and i figured out my problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would check the installed PHP packages on the dev server and compare to the Prod server. fr2.php.net/manual/en/soap.setup.php

Comment: That was the problem; SOAP is not installed on our hosted live server.

Answer (score 0):

This will more than likly be a config setup for php on the live server, but here are the common problems i have had with SOAP on php,

First thing is check the allowed memory for php on live comparable with dev (SOAP is big and bad for memory)

Is the php on the live server the same version as the dev server,

Is the live server authorized to access the SOAP server (if auth is used on an IP Level)

as one of the SOAP packages i have used did this to me i found out there was a version mismatch, last but not least could you tell us what SOAP Library if any other then php default your using so we can help as your code looks good :)

thinking about it have you install soap i don't think php natively supports it i think its a pear or pecl package and if your using XAMPP or easyPHP on dev these have all of both all ready included in php.