# cURL connection refused - can't create new SOAP client on PHP

Tags: php, curl, soap

*I made this question before but found new information so i decided to make a new question with everthing i found.

I've facing the similar issue showed on this questions here, whenever i try to execute a SoapClient function and not only it did not work but also showed no error, on the

```
 new SoapClient($wsdl, $params);
```

function call:

[PHP SoapClient not working - no error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6154250/php-soapclient-not-working-no-error)

however, even after o installed the soap extension on my server:

```
apt-get install php-soap
```

and changed my php.ini file removing the ; from

```
;extensio=soap
```

it did not work

When i go to the phpinfo page it says that soap is enabled:

[image: SOAP enabled]

But somehow it does not execute, when i try to run the command to install it says that soap is already installed

When i look on the configure command on the top of the phpinfo page it includes the

```
  '--enable-soap'
```

line:

[image: phpinfo top]

What am i doing wrong? is some configuration missing?

I run my server with ubuntu 20.4 with openlitespeed installed.

I also restarted the server several times to make sure the installations work correctly.

There is the code i use, i also use this function on my local server and it works normally:

```
 $soapParams = array(
   'login'          => 'Name',
   'password'       => 'password',
   'authentication' => SOAP_AUTHENTICATION_BASIC,
   'trace'          => 1,
   'exceptions'     => 0, );

  $params = array();
  $client = new SoapClient('https://myserver.name:8051/MEX?wsdl', 
   $soapParams);

  $params = array( 'DataServerName' => 'NAME', 
    'PrimaryKey'=>'KEYNAME', 
   );


  $result = $client->ReadRecord($params);

  echo "response:\n" . $client->__getLastResponse() . "<br><br>";
```

[Leroy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2525872/leroy) suggested that i could enable exceptions instead of using is_soap_fault, when i enabled on the **$soapParams** array:

```
 $soapParams = array(
   'login'          => 'Name',
   'password'       => 'password',
   'authentication' => SOAP_AUTHENTICATION_BASIC,
   'trace'          => 1,
   'exceptions'     => 1, );\\Exceptions enabled

  $params = array();
  $client = new SoapClient('https://myserver.name:8051/MEX?wsdl', 
   $soapParams);

  $params = array( 'DataServerName' => 'NAME', 
    'PrimaryKey'=>'KEYNAME', 
   );


  $result = $client->ReadRecord($params);

  echo "response:\n" . $client->__getLastResponse() . "<br><br>";
```

it returned the following error:

```
 Exceção - SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'https://myserver.name:8051/MEX?wsdl' : failed to load external entity "https://myserver.name:8051/MEX?wsdl"
```

It seems that myserver can't load the wsdl, which is wierd since my local server can load it just fine.

I tried executing curl in both my local server and my production server(the one that this error is ocorring), in my local server its responded normally, however in my production server it returned the following error:

```
 root@my-server:/# curl https://myserver.name:8051/MEX?wsdl
 curl: (7) Failed to connect to myserver.name port 8051: Connection refused
```

I looked on the /etc/hosts on my production server and it shows the following:

```
  127.0.0.1       localhost servermyserver
  ::1             localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
  ff02::1         ip6-allnodes
  ff02::2         ip6-allrouters
```

I also executed the command

```
  netstat -ln | grep 80
  netstat -ln | grep 443
```

On my production server,

```
  root@servermyserver:/etc# netstat -ln | grep 443
  tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*                           LISTEN
  tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
  tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
  tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
  tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN
  tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN
  tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN
  tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN
  udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*
  udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*
  udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*
  udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*
  udp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*
  udp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*
  udp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*
  udp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*
  root@servermyserver:/etc# netstat -ln | grep 80
  tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:7080            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
  tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*                     LISTEN
  tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
  tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
  tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
  tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8090            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
  udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:7080            0.0.0.0:*
  unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     2307434806       /usr/local/lsws/admin/tmp/admin.sock.7958
  unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     2308072711 /tmp/lshttpd/facsu7698.sock
```

However, when i run

```
  netstat -ln | grep 8051
```

That is the port i'm trying to connect with soap, it doesn't return anything, it seems like myserver doesn't listen to the port i'm trying to use.

I tried to run cURL with ipv4 to see if i can get some results:

```
  root@servermyserver:/# curl --ipv4 -v "https://myserver.name:8051/MEX?wsdl"
  *   Trying xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx...
  * TCP_NODELAY set
  * connect to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx port 8051 failed: Connection refused
  * Failed to connect to myserver.name:8051 port 8051: Connection refused
  * Closing connection 0
  curl: (7) Failed to connect to myserver.name:8051 port 8051: Connection refused
```

I also tried to run telnet:

```
  root@servermyserve:/# telnet localhost 8051
  Trying ::1...
  Trying 127.0.0.1...
  telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
```

However, if i try telnet to por 80, it responds normally:

```
  root@servermyserve:/# telnet localhost 80
  Trying ::1...
  Trying 127.0.0.1...
  Connected to localhost.
  Escape character is '^]'.
```